# Аутентификация пользователя

Tags: аутентификация, php, mysql

Как происходит аутентификация в любой соц.сети, когда после ввода логина и пароля, если не выйти, то будешь автоматически аутентифицироваться? Я раньше думал, что через сессии, но они не вечны.

Comment: если не выйти, то будешь автоматически аутентифицироваться
    объясните пожалуйста что это значить ? Не закрывая браузер(просто открывая новую вкладку)?(в этом случае да,сессий) или начиная новую сессию форселогиниться?(а в этом случае кукий)

Comment: Вопрос про реализацию функции «Запомнить меня», верно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Через автопродление сессии через cookies.

php.ini

```
session.use_cookies = 1
```